# Modifying an object inside of a running thread in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

So I'm currently working on a simple messaging client application in Java, and I'm having some issues. The back end of my program is essentially just two threads: a listener that constantly waits for messages on a specified port, and a messenger, which is supposed to check a specific queue to see if there are any outgoing messages,and send them if it does. The queue is defined outside of the thread, and it's updated with messages via a separate function. I have verified that outside of the thread, the queue is populated and has the proper messages; however, inside of the thread, the the queue is completely empty.

I've tried a few workarounds to allow the thread to read the data in the queue, such as creating a "readQueue" function, but nothing seems to allow me to get the data out of the queue in the thread. What am I missing here? Is this normal thread behavior, or am I doing something wrong? I've attached a few relevant code snippets to give you a better idea of what exactly I've got going on.

The messenger thread:

```
    Runnable messenger = () -> {
        try {
            while(true) {

               if( messageQueue.peek() != null) {
                System.out.println(messageQueue.poll().message);
               }

            }
        }

        catch(Exception e) { 
            System.out.println("that really wasn't suposed to happen");
        }
    };
    Thread thread2 = new Thread(messenger);
    thread2.start();
```

The method for adding new messages to the queue:

```
public static void addMessage(String message) {
    if(!message.isEmpty()) {
         messageQueue.add(messagePacket);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your while loop have some sleep (or similar) ? otherwise that is going to be a very busy loop.

Comment: Have you verified that the reading thread hold a reference to the correct queue?

Comment: As of right now, no, it doesn't have any sleep. Is it bad to have it just running like that  all the time?

Comment: I have not verified that the reading thread is actually referencing the correct queue; I guess that's a major part of my issue. How would I begin to test something like this?

Comment: @FyreFly00 `Is it bad to have it just running like that.. ` It will make a cpu core busy to almost 100%. You may use only the `poll()` method and if it returns null, sleep for some time, e. g. `Thread. sleep(200)`. Or you may use `BlockingQueue` where you can use blocking poll with some timeout.

Comment: Could you share more of the code? What claas is the queue? (is it thread-safe?) Is the queue a class instance or final method variable? From the provided code it is not clear why it may not work. To check if you have a correct obj. reference you simply debug in your IDE

Comment: Adding to what @gusto2 said: Without proper synchronization between the two threads, there is no way to know when, _if ever_, the `messenger` thread will see any change to the queue made by the other thread.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/memconsist.html

Comment: P.S., instead of looping until `q.peek()` returns something, why don't you simply `q.take()` from a _blocking_ queue?  `q.take()` _waits_ until there is something in the queue to be taken.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code in a single Java class with a main method. It is working fine for me. Instead of a listener at a port, however, I used inputs from console and called `addMessage()`. The `messenger` is able to pick up from the queue and print.

**Edit: Added the class for your reference**

```
public class TestClass{
private static Queue<Message> messageQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

public static void main( String[] args ){
    Runnable messenger = () -> {
        try{
            while( true ){
                if( messageQueue.peek() != null ){
                    String message = messageQueue.poll().message;
                    if( message.equalsIgnoreCase( "stop" ) ) break;

                    System.out.println( message );
                }
            }
        }

        catch( Exception e ){
            System.out.println( "that really wasn't suposed to happen" );
        }
    };

    Thread thread2 = new Thread( messenger );
    thread2.start();

    readFromConsole( input -> {
        addMessage( input );
    } );
}

public static void addMessage( String message ){
    if( !message.isEmpty() ){
        Message m = new Message( message );
        messageQueue.add( m );
    }
}

private static void readFromConsole( Consumer<String> consumer ) {
    try( Scanner in = new Scanner( new FilterInputStream( System.in ){ public void close(){} } ) ){
        while( true ) {
            System.out.print( "> " );
            String input = in.nextLine();
            if( input == null || input.trim().equals( "" ) ) {
                System.out.println( "Closing..." );
                break;
            }

            consumer.accept( input );
        }
    }
}

private static class Message{
    public String message;

    public Message( String message ){
        super();
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Wow, this a very comprehensive solution, and honestly something I didn't even think of doing. This  has given me a few ideas of what I can try messing around with to get stuff passed in.